# Add migration for DTO in other DTO in room

Tags: android, android-room

I have DTO:

```
@Entity(tableName = "product")
data class ProductDTO(
        @Embedded
        val attributes: AttributesDTO,
        val autocomplete: String,
        val basePhoto: String,
        val baseColors: BaseColors) {
   
}
```

and Attribute DTO

```
@Entity(tableName = "attributes")
class AttributesDTO {
    @PrimaryKey
    var attributeId: Long = 0
    var battery: String = ""
    var brand: String = ""

    constructor(battery: String, brand: String) {
        this.battery = battery
        this.brand = brand
    }
}
```

I want to add new field `Price` to `AttributeDTO` and need to create migration for that. In database preview I can see that all fields from AttributeDTO are available in ProductDTO table. How can I do that? Room version: 2.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

By following [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions):

First add your attribute to your class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "attributes")
class AttributesDTO {
    @PrimaryKey
    var attributeId: Long = 0
    var battery: String = ""
    var brand: String = ""
    var price: Int?

    constructor(battery: String, brand: String) {
        this.battery = battery
        this.brand = brand
    }
}
```

You can add Automatic migration or manual migration:

For Automatic migration:

just add this annotation:

```
@Database(
  version = 2,
  entities = [AttributeDTO::class],
  autoMigrations = [
    AutoMigration (from = 1, to = 2)
  ]
)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
  ...
}
```

Manual migration:

```
val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
  override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
    database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE attributes ADD COLUMN price INTEGER")
  }
}
```

And when you create your Room database add it:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, "Sample.db")
    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
    .build()
```

Comment: In Room version: 2.2.5 there is no automigration